# How can I edit fields in SmartGWT's DetailViewer?

Tags: gwt, smartgwt

Tell me, please! I am using SmartGWT 2.4.

How can I edit any fields in `DetailViewer`? (com.smartgwt.client.widgets.viewer.DetailViewer)

For example, fields in ListGrid (com.smartgwt.client.widgets.grid.ListGrid) can be made editable by setting `ListGridField.setCanEdit(true)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. DetailViewer is not meant to be used for editing values - it's only for viewing.